# getting an int to 2 significant figures

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm converting MPH into Minute miles with the following code:

```
double fastestAvgMPH = [fastestRun doubleValue];
            int minutes = 60/fastestAvgMPH;
            double seconds = fmod(60, fastestAvgMPH);
            int realSeconds = seconds * 60;
            _fastestRunSpeedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d/mi",minutes,realSeconds];
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the int value for real seconds is over 2 significant figures. one example is 06:431/mi .

I'm sure this is a really simple fix, but how do I round an int to 2 significant figures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
double fastestAvgMPH = [fastestRun doubleValue];
int secondsPerMile = 3600 / fastestAvgMPH;
int minutes = secondsPerMile / 60;
int seconds = secondsPerMile % 60;
_fastestRunSpeedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d/mi", minutes, seconds];
```